# Getting error, While writing test class in salesforce, "Variable does not exist" = bypassTrigger

Tags: apex, unit-test

While trying to run the test class, I am getting below error:

> Variable does not exist : bypassTrigger

```
@isTest
private class ArtistSelectionControllerTest {
    @isTest
    private static void testTest() {
        EducationEventServices.bypassTrigger = true;
        ...
    }
}
```

EducationEventServices class:

```
public class EducationEventServices
{
    @TestVisible static final String EVENT_REQUEST_STATUS_CANCELLED = 'Cancelled';
    @TestVisible static final String SPEAKER_STATUS_CANCELLED = 'Canceled';

    public static Select.Filter isStatusCancelled = Select.Field.isEqual( Event__c.Event_Request_Status__c, EVENT_REQUEST_STATUS_CANCELLED );
    public static Select.Filter hasStatusChangedToCancelled = Select.Field.hasChanged( Event__c.Event_Request_Status__c ).andx( isStatusCancelled );

    public static List<Educator__c> educatorsWithStatusChangedToCancelled( List<Event__c> eventsIn )
    {
        List<Educator__c> educatorsToUpdate = new List<Educator__c>();
        for( Educator__c educator : [ SELECT Id FROM Educator__c WHERE Event__c IN :eventsIn ] )
        {
            educator.Speaker_Status__c = SPEAKER_STATUS_CANCELLED;
            educatorsToUpdate.add( educator );
        }
        return educatorsToUpdate;
    }

    //Education Event date must be in GMT time
    public static DateTime getEventStartDateTime(Event__c edEvt){
        if(edEvt.Event_Start_Date__c == null || String.isBlank(edEvt.Start_Time__c))
            throw new EducationEventServicesException('The Event Start Date and Start Time fields are required to be populated.');

        return new Util_DateTime.ParsedDate(edEvt.Event_Start_Date__c, edEvt.Start_Time__c).getDateTime();

    }

    //Education Event date must be in GMT time
    public static DateTime getEventEndDateTime(Event__c edEvt){
        if(edEvt.Event_End_Date__c == null || String.isBlank(edEvt.Class_End_Time__c))
            throw new EducationEventServicesException('The Event End Date and End Time fields are required to be populated.');

        return new Util_DateTime.ParsedDate(edEvt.Event_End_Date__c, edEvt.Class_End_Time__c).getDateTime();
    }

    public static void updateCEMonitorTimes( List<Event__c> updatedEducationEvents, Map<Id, Event__c> oldEducationEventMap )
    {
        // Filter education events where the start date or end date have changed
        Map<Id, Event__c> filteredEducationEvents = new Map<Id, Event__c>();

        for(Event__c anUpdatedEducationEvent : updatedEducationEvents){
            if(anUpdatedEducationEvent.Event_Start_Date__c != oldEducationEventMap.get(anUpdatedEducationEvent.Id).Event_Start_Date__c ||
                oldEducationEventMap.get(anUpdatedEducationEvent.Id).Event_End_Date__c != anUpdatedEducationEvent.Event_End_Date__c){
                filteredEducationEvents.put(anUpdatedEducationEvent.Id, anUpdatedEducationEvent);                
            }
        }

        Set<Id> filteredEducationEventIds = filteredEducationEvents.keySet();

        // Update related CE monitors with new start date and end dates
        if(!filteredEducationEventIds.isEmpty()){
            List<CE_Monitors__c> relatedCeMonitors = [SELECT Id, Event__c FROM CE_Monitors__c WHERE Event__c IN : filteredEducationEventIds];

            for(CE_Monitors__c aRelatedCeMonitor : relatedCeMonitors){
                Id relatedEventId = aRelatedCeMonitor.Event__c;

                // Retrieve event start date and event end date
                if(filteredEducationEvents.containsKey(relatedEventId)){
                    Event__c relatedEvent = filteredEducationEvents.get(relatedEventId);

                    aRelatedCeMonitor.Event_Start_Date__c = relatedEvent.Event_Start_Date__c;
                    aRelatedCeMonitor.Event_End_Date__c   = relatedEvent.Event_End_Date__c;
                }
            }

            if(!relatedCeMonitors.isEmpty()){
                doDMLOperation(relatedCeMonitors, filteredEducationEvents);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void doDMLOperation(List<CE_Monitors__c> ceMonitorsToUpdate, Map<Id, Event__c> idToFilteredEventMap)
    {
        try
        {
            update ceMonitorsToUpdate;
        }
        catch( DMLException dmlE )
        {
            for(Integer i = 0; i<dmlE.getNumDML(); i++)
            {
                Event__c errorEvent = idToFilteredEventMap.get(ceMonitorsToUpdate.get(dmlE.getDMLIndex(i)).Event__c);
                errorEvent.addError(dmlE);
            }

        }
    }

    private class EducationEventServicesException extends Exception{}
}
```

Comment: So...is there any such variable in your `EducationEventServices` class? Please include the content of that class or it will be impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I didnt find any variable in my EducationEventServices.

Comment: So remove the line where you are trying to set that variable...

Answer (score 1):

bypassTrigger does not exist in your class. Also if you want to Bypass the trigger while running test classes, why are you using variable in class. You can create a custom setting where you can maintain this flag from your apex class.